# How much the Concorde secondary nozzle contribute to thrust?

Tags: jet-engine, thrust, concorde

Does anybody knows how much did secondary nozzles **bucket type** on the Concorde's engines contributed to the increase of thrust during take of and sub-sonic flight? This is picture of the nozzles [image: nozzle modes] and here is air flow during take of [image] all images from this link https://www.heritageconcorde.com/variable-exhaust-nozzles  source states that secondary nozzles reduces noise, as well as improved engine performance. I suppose performance means thrust?

Comment: I added diagram to my question.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://www.heritageconcorde.com/variable-exhaust-nozzles) source suggests at subsonic speeds, the secondary reduces drag but doesn't contribute significantly to thrust.

> At all times below Mach 0.55 – on the ground, take-off and initial
>   climb – the buckets are set to 21 deg., forming a ‘jet-pump’ gap at
>   the nacelle trailing-edge. The high speed jet exiting from the primary
>   nozzle draws-in atmosphere air from above and below the nacelle to
>   eradicate a source of base drag that would otherwise exit between the
>   nozzles.